# NSDictionary objectAtIndex causing an unrecognized selector exception

Tags: objective-c, object, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I've got arrays in a NSMutableDictionary which is named favToLoad. I'm trying to get the arrays one by one with the indexPath.row of a UITableView.

**Code :**

```
NSArray* fav = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"IndexPath = %d", indexPath.row);
fav = [favToLoad objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Fav = %@", fav);
```

The error:

```
[NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

**Solution**

I've solved my problem by using NSMutableArray instead of NSMutableDictionary

Comment: As the error states you are sending an `objectAtIndex:` message to a `NSDictionary`, which doesn't know how to answer to it. You should use `objectForKey:`

Comment: I don't have "objectForKey", it doesn't suggest it :(

Comment: Put this log in: NSLog(@"%@",[favToLoad class]) What does it show?

Comment: I got this :
2013-02-20 23:17:48.014 PEBKAC[2232:907] __NSCFDictionary
2013-02-20 23:17:48.015 PEBKAC[2232:907] IndexPath = 0
2013-02-20 23:17:48.016 PEBKAC[2232:907] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f0a0b80`

Comment: We know it's a dictionary, the error message is pretty clear that `favToLoad` is an `NSCFDictionary`.  Where does `favToLoad` come from?  Xcode doesn't *suggest* `objectForKey` because in the context you're typing it's probably either an `id` pointer or it can't be otherwise inferred.  Show `favToLoad`'s declaration and assignment and the answer will probably be there.

Comment: You were right I made a mistake in the declaration of favtoload --' But now how fav can be the object of favtoload at indexPath.row ?

Comment: To answer that, you need to look at how `fav` found its way into `favToLoad` in the first place.  If it was inserted with `setObject:forKey:` then `objectForKey:` will extract it.

Comment: As an aside, you probably don't want NSArray* fav = [[NSArray alloc] init];. You either want NSArray *fav = [favToLoad objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];, or NSArray *fav = nil;. Making an extra array and then throwing it away immediately is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have indices. You can't do this. Instead, you need to use -objectForKey: with the appropriate key to get the value you want (you can use 'po favToLoad' in the debugger to inspect the contents).

Comment: I don't have "objectForKey", it doesn't suggest it :(

Comment: Armand: please include the declaration of "favToLoad" in your post then. It's likely that it's not what you think it is.

Comment: **Swift 2.0:** this is how you access `ObjectForKey` =  `inArray[FindObject]`

Answer (score 1):

you should use `objectForKey:` instead of `objectAtIndex:`

`objectAtIndex:` valid for `NSArray` classes